# How can I show that two sets are disjoint?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem that was on my Discrete math exam. The problem was as follows:

> If $\overline{A}\cap B=B$ and $\overline{B}\cap A=A$, then what can you conclude about $A$ and $B$?

Obviously, the question is vague but I'm pretty sure $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. However, I can't figure out to prove this. If they're not disjoint, how would I prove that? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your $\bar{A}$ stand for the complement of $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's the notation I'm using.

Comment: Actually, $\overline A\cap B=B\iff\overline B\cap A=A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary set theory proofs are but logic in disguise.

The first statement can be translated to "If x belongs to B, then x belongs to B (which is trivial) and x does not belong to A.

In short if x is in B then it is not in A.

Now do it again with the second statement, you have your proof.

Comment: Would "if x is in B, then it is not in A" be expressed as $B\not\subseteq A$?

Comment: @DanielLi $B \not\subseteq A$ would logically be equivalent to "There is some $x \in B$ such that $x \not\in A$."  In contrast, "[for all $x$] if $x$ is in $B$, then it is not in $A$" would be $B \subseteq \bar{A}$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I misunderstood that $B\not\subseteq A=B\subseteq\overline{A}$, so when I got that $(B\not\subseteq A\wedge A\not\subseteq B)$ implies that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, I was confused.

Comment: As noted by  Hagen von Eitzen, the two statements are in fact equivalent. You don't need to "do it again with the second statement." You just proved that the 1st one was equivalent to $B\subset\bar A$, i.e. in fact to $B\cap A=\varnothing.$ (By symmetry, it proves Hagen von Eitzen claim.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use associativity of $\ \cap$

$A\cap B=(\bar B\cap A)\cap(\bar A\cap B)=\bar B\cap(\overbrace{A\cap\bar A}^{\varnothing})\cap B=\varnothing$

And $A,B$ are disjoint.